# printf parameter generated in running time

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting

Basically I have a struct with a few float variables for hold inches data for different things. And I want convert this data to a string for print out.

I want convert for example this float value `"1.50"` to this `"1 f 0.5 inches"` for use in a `print("%s %s", convertToText(node -> data1), convertToText(node -> data2))` or something like that. But I am a bit confused to how implement this in c. So each `"%s"` needs be `"1 f 0.5 in"` but with his data converted.

Comment: Please show your own effort so far, and explain what you are confused about.

Comment: Aside: Are you sure you don't want `1.5` to convert to `1 f 6 inches`, which would be the correct way to convert your floating-point value if its units are feet?

Answer (score 1):

You could find out the integer, and then calculate the mod of the value.

```
float input;
float decimal;
int integer;

scanf("%f", &input);

decimal = input%;
integer = input - decimal;
printf("%i f %f inches", integer, decimal);
```

Comment: You might consider extending this answer to include a function that *returns* this string, rather than just printing it. More widely useful -- can be used if the job involves writing the string to a file, sending it over a network, checking its length for formatting, etc.

Comment: What is `decimal = input%;`?

Comment: It's the Modulus of the value.

Comment: `input%` is not standard C syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
prtinff("%f", myFloat);
```

Will print your float directly to STDOUT.

```
char myStr[50];
sprintf(myStr,"%f",myFloat);
```

Will convert a float into a string that you can work with.

You can use strcat() to join strings. You can use int() to determine the whole parts of a float.

Comment: Rather than `50`, maybe `FLT_MAX_10_EXP +11` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sprintf` for this under `string.h`

```
 char buffer [50];
     double i=10.55;
      sprintf (buffer, "%lf ",i);
      printf ("%s \n",buffer);
```

now edit the string as you like.
for more information you can see [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

Comment: It is reasonable to expect code to cope with `double` over its entire range including values like `1e300`.  Suggest `char buffer [DBL_MAX_10_EXP + 10];`

Answer (score 0):

To cope with proper rounding, etc. multiply by 12 first, then by the required precision and then segment the number.

---

This avoids `7.99999` --> `7 f 12.0 inch`, instead we get `8 f 0.0 inch`

When the number is negative, do not repeat the sign in the "inch" field.

Work over entire range of `float` which exceeds `int`.

```
#include <math.h>

int printf_feet_inches_tenths(float distance) {
  double d = round(distance * 12.0 * 10); // convert to exact 1/10 of inch
  double inch_tenths = fmod(d, 12 * 10);
  double feet = (d - inch_tenths) / (12 * 10);
  return printf("%.0f f %.1f inch\n", feet, fabs(inch_tenths) / 10);
}

void printf_feet_inches_tenths_test(void) {
  printf_feet_inches_tenths(7.5);
  printf_feet_inches_tenths(7.999);
  printf_feet_inches_tenths(-1.5);
  printf_feet_inches_tenths(1e30);
}
```

Output

```
7 f 6.0 inch
8 f 0.0 inch
-1 f 6.0 inch
1000000015047466219876688855040 f 0.0 inch
```